# View inheritance problem

Tags: spring-webflow

I have copied this question here from [spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=93491).

I have a parent flow and a child flow. The parent flow has following folder structure

```
parent
    |
    |--parent-flow.xml
    |--parentView.xhtml
```

This parent has following view-state

```
   <view-state id="parentState" view="parentView.xhtml">
    </view-state>
```

Child flow looks like this:

```
<flow ...
        parent="parent">
...
    <view-state id="test">
        <transition on="bang" to="parentState"/>
    </view-state>
...
</flow>
```

The problem is when I hit 'bang' action of child flow it can't see parentView.xhtml view in parent flow. I get something like this:
Code:

```
The requested resource (/spring/child?execution=e3s2) is not available.
```

If I copy parentView.xhtml into child's flow folder, everything works as a charm.

I wonder if it is a defect or it was designed to work like this? If it's a defect, then it worse opening JIRA ticket... This situation is quite common I think, for example in my case I have delete conformation screen (parent view-state) that is used in all pages where user is able to delete entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround for the issue:
One can specify relative path in view attribute. The example below works if you specify parent view like that:

```
<view-state id="parentState" view="../parent/parentView.xhtml">
    </view-state>
```